# Flask admin , update a column after_model_change not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have successfully overridden `on_model_change` in flask but when I try to do the same for `after_model_change` it does nothing , how to make changes to model after model changes ?

```
Class CustomAdminView(ModelView):  # pylint: disable=no-init

    #works fine and udpates the column
    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        curr_user = getpass.getuser()
        model.updatedby = curr_user

    #does nothing to the model
    def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        current_remarks= model.remarks
        model.rhistory = f'changes made : {current_remarks}'
```

What I am doing is get the current remarks and update it to the history , but I can get the remarks column data after only it has been updated to the model
If its not possible to do this in make changes after model has been updated ,Can I get the value of the the remarks which user is entering so that I can update it during model update.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the `after_model_change` [docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/model/base/#BaseModelView.after_model_change) you can see that the model has already been committed. If you want to change the model in this method you need to commit the changes to the database. e.g.

```
def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
    current_remarks= model.remarks
    model.rhistory = f'changes made : {current_remarks}'
    try:
        db.session.commit():
    except Exception as ex:
        db.session.rollback()
        #  handle error
```

You ask, "Can I get the value of the the remarks which user is entering so that I can update it during model update". Of course you can, providing the remarks field is present in the create/edit form. e.g. The form passed in the `on_model_change(form, model, is_created)` is the form used to create/update model - see the [docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/?highlight=on_model_change#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.on_model_change). e.g.

```
#works fine and udpates the column
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
    curr_user = getpass.getuser()
    model.updatedby = curr_user

    # assume form has a field called remarks
    model.remarks = form.remarks.data
```

Comment: Error @ db.session.commit() , I can use the second snippet of code but , first one can not commit the changes , I am passing the "session = db.session" , but neither session.commit() works nor db.session.commit()